# How to acess the pair value from vector of pairs in c++

Tags: c++11, vector

I am acessing the value of pair of vector in the following way.

```
for(unordered_map<int,vector<pair<int,int>>>::iterator it;it!=mul2.end();it++)
{
    int value=it->first;
    if(value%p!=0)
        continue;
    int quotient=value/p;
    auto it1=mul1.find(quotient*q);
    if(it1==mul1.end())
        continue;
    vector<pair<int,int>> list1=it->second;
    vector<pair<int,int>> list2=it1->second;
    for(int j=0;j<list1.size();j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<list2.size();k++)
        {
            if((list1[i]).second!=(list[2]).first)
            {
                flag=1;break;
            }
            if(flag)
                break;
        }
    }
    if(flag)
        break;
}
if(flag)
    printf("Yes\n");
else
    printf("No\n");
```

when I access list[i].second, it is giving me the following error.

```
error: missing template arguments before ‘[’ token
```

I know how to access it with iterator but I don't know what is wrong in this approach.

Comment: The code above [is syntactically correct](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77b4958637e209e6), please post a minimal example.

Comment: First can you try e.g. `make_pair<int, int>(2, 3)` (should work anyway), and if that doesn't work then please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, and include the complete build-log.

Comment: I guess you have `vector[0].first;`, it's the only possibility to trigger this error

Comment: kk I am posting my actual code .....

Comment: `list[2]` -> `list2[k]`

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki yes you are right

Comment: yes.. thanks for suggestion

Comment: @Piotr  But it will not change that error... please help me why i am getting this error. If you want I can post the whole code which can run .. Now I have posted just that part which is showing error

Comment: Try simplifying the code to the minimum, then re-post it. Remove everything that's not necessary.